# Speed up a for loop when checking variables in two long nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I have two nested lists containing 15000 lists each with 5 variables per list. I check two variables from each sublist against the other to look for matches. If there is a match on both variables, nothing should be done, if there is NOT a match a variable from sublist `lagerProduct` should be set to 0 and `lagerProduct` should be appended to `self.mainlist`. The final output is `self.mainlist` that cointains all of `self.hovedfil` + sublists from `self.lagerfil`. The working code is below but it is not very fast. How can i speed it up?

```
match = False
self.lagerFil = self.mainlist #15000 sublists with 5 values in each sublist
self.hovedFil = [[]] #15000 sublists with 5 values in each sublist
for lagerProduct in self.lagerFil:
    for produktHoved in self.hovedFil:
        if lagerProduct[0] == produktHoved[0] and lagerProduct[3] == produktHoved[3]:
            match = True

    if match == False:
        lagerProduct [4] = 0
        self.mainlist.append(lagerProduct)
    else:
        match = False
```

Comment: What is the final output of your code - `self.mainlist`?

Comment: @Nurzhan yea, should be self.mainlist

Comment: It's a bit confusing you already assign `self.mainlist` to `self.lagerfil` and then you append element from `self.lagerfil` to `mainlist`. You also have typos in your code.

Comment: If i loop directly over 'self.mainlist' i end up with a "never ending" for loop as new items will be appended to the end of 'self.mainlist' ?

Comment: Is there a chance to put the lists in pandas dataframe and join the two lists by the two elements you want to check?

Comment: @RysDe absolutely, the lists are loaded from CSV's with pandas. Can you suggest how i can accomplish what you wrote? Is it possible to set   'lagerProduct[4] = 0' this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that for each of 15000 elements in mainlist you iterate over 15000 elements in hovedFil (even after finding a match you continue to check the remaining elements), that is 225 million iterations.

There are also other problems, such as that you are iterating over self.mainlsit while also appending to it (just assigning another name to the list does not copy the list).

You should convert hovedFil into a `set()` and then the search becomes O(1), and should build a separate list with the matched products:

```
matches = set((p[0], p[3]) for p in self.hovedFil)
matchedProducts = [
    lagerProduct for lagerProduct in self.lagerFil
    if (lagerProduct[0], lagerProduct[3]) not in matches]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didnt not know list2 = list1 didnt make a copy, and it seems that by using list2 = list(list1) things sped up quite alot as i dont have to iterate over appended values :) the reason i assignes self.mainlist to a new variable was to avoid iterating over the appended values. I will look into the rest of your answer and try to learn something new. Thanks again!